# Best place to put classes that extend the .net framework?

Tags: naming

I have no clue where to put the following class and I've noticed I just keep putting them in a helpers folder which isn't much helpfull towards reusability in future projects.

**Example:** 
I want to have the ability to use the `DisplayNameAttribute` together with resource files. In order for this to work I made a `LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute` which inherits the ´DisplayNameAttribute´ and adds the following properties `DisplayNameResourceName` and `DisplayNameResourceType`.

In which namespace/location would you place such a class which is likely to be reused in future projects?

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate if it were asked on StackOverflow.com

Comment: Over there I got the following warning after entering this same title: `The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is putting all helper classes and methods in a separate project, and then reference this project in each solution you create. Much easier than copying folders from place x to place y.

This project with all kinds of extensions, helpers etc, can be called something like "Company.Core", or similar.

Example (your attributes):

```
using Company.Core.Attributes;

// ....

[LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute.DisplayNameResourceName("ResourceName"),
...]
public string Example { get; set; }
```